# When can we use random effects?

Tags: mixed-model, panel-data, probit

I use a probit model with longitudinal data including the same individuals (here customers) for 9 months. My dependant variable (event: does customer leave the company this month) is binary. The event may occur at most once so if this event occurs at a specific month, post observations of this customer are dropped.

I got the recommendation to add the customer as random effect as the behaviours of the same customer might be correlated across months. My question: does it make sense in this context to use the customer as random effect ?  I mean here for a binary dependant variable where the value 1 may occur at most once for every customer? I think that the random intercept would already capture most of the information.

Comment: Have you considered survival analysis with time-varying covariates? This may be a more suitable modelling strategy than binary regression

Comment: It is indeed another option, but we are currently more interested in the drivers leading to the event than to the drivers linked to time to event. Thanks anyway for your suggestion.

Comment: Survival analysis is still compatible with your stated interests. Random effects is an appropriate way to account for corellation within customers, but if you don't account for the fact that many clusters (customers) will have zero events (customer doesn't leave the company) and the rest will only have one, then you'll run into problems. This is akin to a subject-level zero-inflation problem (see http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0962280216683740) except you have maximum one event per cluster. I really would recommend survival methods.